# How to next column when finished writing column in phpspreadsheet?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, report, phpspreadsheet

I have an issue write data vertically.
I don't know how to next column when finished a column. Please help me.

Report example:

[image]

My data:
[image]
Thanks!!!

Comment: Did you write your function ? if so, put it in your post to better help you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all.
I had solution is use: setCellValueByColumnAndRow()